# Lazy evaluation Xcode 10.2+

Tags: swift, xcode, lazy-evaluation

I noticed a different behaviour in the lazy evaluation with Xcode 10.2+.

If I have the current code:

```
class C {

    private let myString: String?
    private let tag: Int

    init(string: String?, tag: Int) {
        myString = string
        self.tag = tag
    }

    func f() -> String? {
        print("\(tag) called")
        return myString
    }
}

let a = C(string: nil, tag: 0)
let b = C(string: "2", tag: 1)
let c = C(string: nil, tag: 2)

let array = [a, b, c]

let string = array.lazy.compactMap { $0.f() }.first
```

I would expect the output:

```
0 called
1 called
```

(which I have with Xcode 10.1)

but it's actually:

```
0 called
1 called
1 called // called twice
```

I wouldn't say it's an issue with Swift 5 because my project is still using Swift 4.0

Comment: Does using Swift 4.0 in the new Xcode mean it uses the older compiler? Or how does that work?

Comment: Hi @RakeshaShastri, I didn't change any compiler modes as far as I see in the git changes. Just switching between Xcode versions.

Comment: I can confirm the observed different behavior in Xcode 10.1 vs Xcode 10.2.1.

Comment: I think this question would be better posted at apple

Comment: Probably due to [#18075](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/18075) – note that the number of times such a lazily evaluated transform is called is ultimately an implementation detail, and as such shouldn't have side effects.

Comment: This has been  reported   as https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10270 and  closed as “invalid”. Jordan Rose wrote: *“Sorry, this is also correct. The lazy sequences in Swift do not cache their results, as a deliberate design choice.”*

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the ticket and PR. My "Googling" skills are not as good as I was thinking :P